# Join one to many

Tags: mysql, one-to-many

I have two tables,

The first table has a Primary Key called PKID 
table A:

```
PKID     | name
------ | ------
1      | A
2      | b
```

The second table has the PKID column from table A as a foreign key
table B:

```
PKID     | name
------ | ------
1      | true
1      | false
2      | false
2      | false
2      | false
```

I need select all rows from  table A when all child's have ( false ) value from table B

I would like output the following table :

```
id     | name
------ | ------
2      | b
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SELECT * from A LEFT JOIN B on B.PKID=B.PKID where B.name ='false'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query for this, GROUP_CONCAT function will be useful in this case

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.name) as allData,B.PKID FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.PKID = B.PKID GROUP BY B.PKID HAVING allData="false"`